# Python lists changing eachother

Tags: python, list, object

In the code here:

```
movexy = posgrid[tileclicked1] #
while movexy[x] > tempxy[x]:
    print movexy
    print posgrid[tileclicked1]

    movexy[x] -= 1
```

Where the value of `posgrid[tileclicked1] = [75, 120]`
And the variable `x = 0`

I've encountered the problem that when I subtract one from `movexy[x]`, one is also automatically subtracted from the list from which it got it's value, posgrid... How come? I create the `movexy` list only in order to have the `posgrid` list remain unchanged. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Here, you are not creating a new list. Both are pointing to the same list.

You can copy list in different ways.For example,

```
New_list = old_list[:]
```